# CURL: grabbing liveleak video

Tags: linux, bash, curl, wget

Can i grab a video using curl?
I was using a website to download videos from liveleak, but it stopped working. I need this for one of my scripts.

basically this is the link:
http://www.liveleak.com/e/955_1345380192

**redirected to this** 
http://edge.liveleak.com/80281E/u/u/ll2_player_files/mp55/player.swf?config=http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config%26item_token=955_1345380192%26embed=1%26extra_params=

**and that conf link contains the video link**. every time i try to download it, i get
--->Make sure a file_url, file_token or playlist_token are set!
http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config%26item_token=955_1345380192%26embed=1%26extra_params=

what I've tried so far:

```
    curl http://edge.liveleak.com/80281E/u/u/ll2_player_files/mp55/player.swf?config=http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config%26item_token=955_1345380192%26embed=1%26extra_params= -s -L -b LCOOKIE -c LCOOKIE -o LIVE

    curl http://edge.liveleak.com/80281E/u/u/ll2_player_files/mp55/player.swf?config=http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config%26item_token=955_1345380192%26embed=1%26extra_params= -I

    curl http://edge.liveleak.com/80281E/u/u/ll2_player_files/mp55/player.swf?config=http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config%26item_token=955_1345380192%26embed=1%26extra_params= -v

    curl http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config&item_token=955_1345380192&embed=1&extra_params=

    wget http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config&item_token=955_1345380192&embed=1&extra_params=

curl  -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; ru; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.15" http://www.liveleak.com/player?a=config&item_token=955_1345380192&embed=1&extra_params=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your epic one-liner:

```
UA="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; ru; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.15"; curl -A "$UA" $(sed -n -e 's/.*<file>\(.*\)<\/file>.*/\1/p' <(wget -q -O - $(wget -U "$UA" -nv -r -np -nd -H --spider "http://www.liveleak.com/e/955_1345380192" 2>&1 | egrep ' URL:' | awk '{print $4}' | sed "s/.*\?config\=//g" | sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' | xargs echo -e)))
```

As requested, it uses curl (and few additional tools); see bash manual and documentation of other commands for explanation.

**Short summary**: they moved information about video in xml file. To have it easy next time use the latest Firefox and it's ability to spy on all HTTP request and log their contents (no add-ons needed!)