# LiveLeak: API / Video Metadata

Tags: api, video, embed

the only slightly helpful thing I could find regarding LiveLeak API was this Question on Stackexchange: [CURL: grabbing liveleak video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246223/curl-grabbing-liveleak-video)

If I only have got the Video URL (e.g. http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=numbered_videoid), is there a way to get video meta data without pulling the whole page? xml or json ideally?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like they work with [Embed.ly](http://embed.ly/providers#infoliveleak), which is a service that transforms a link into a variety of different content streams. Since there seems to be a [RESTful API](http://embed.ly/docs/libraries) and a PHP library (using cURL, or course), if you're worried about extracting video URLs from an HTML document, that seems a reasonable alternative. It's also free to a large degree (unless you're going to bombard their servers with more than 10k requests a month). If you want metadata, though, you have to pay, but you do get the embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveLeak's 'API' is at best their RSS Feeds.

The best I could do was to download the 'internal' page for a certain videoid by appending `&ajax=1` to the url:

```
http://mobile.liveleak.com/view?i=100_1338007444&ajax=1
```

This saved **10.06** KB of bandwidth (about 32%).